# Error while installing tensorflow-cloud with pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, pip, cython

I'm getting following error (it's trimmed considerably as it the whole output was lengthy):

```
$ pip install tensorflow-cloud
Collecting tensorflow-cloud
  Using cached tensorflow_cloud-0.1.16-py3-none-any.whl (92 kB)

... 

Collecting pyarrow<3,>=1
  Downloading pyarrow-2.0.0.tar.gz (58.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 58.9/58.9 MB 4.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... |

error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3612 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
      Collecting cython>=0.29
        Downloading Cython-0.29.28-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (1.9 MB)
           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.9/1.9 MB 4.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
           
...

            In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026,
                             from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:106,
                             from numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:4:
            /usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
              446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                  |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o.d" failed with exit status 1
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
```

System details:

- Python 3.9.7
- pip 22.0.3
- Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: FWIW, you have omitted the actual error message (there must be more information than "exist status 1" somewhere above).